# Django - Repeated variable in path when redirecting

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-validation

I'm trying to redirect my project to a different page in case there is a validation error, but for some reason, I get the variables twice.

```
    context = {
        "job": Job.objects.get(id=job_id)
    }
    return render(request, "trip.html", context)

def update(request, job_id):
    errors = Job.objects.helper_validator(request.POST)
    print(errors)
    if len(errors) > 0:
        for key, value in errors.items():
            messages.error(request, value)
            return redirect(f'dashboard/{job_id}/update')
    else:
        job = Job.objects.get(id=job_id)
        job.title = request.POST["title"]
        job.desc = request.POST["desc"]
        job.location = request.POST["location"]
        job.save()
        return redirect("/dashboard/")
```

```
    path('dashboard/<int:job_id>/update', views.update),
```

the error: The current path, dashboard/5/dashboard/5/update, didn't match any of these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is you are using the `redirect` function in the wrong way:
So instead of using this:

```py
return redirect(f'dashboard/{job_id}/update')
```

Just append **slashes** in the start of url like this:

```py
return redirect(f'/dashboard/{job_id}/update')
```

#### Some other ways to redirect to specific URLs.

1. You can define a specific name for each `view` in **urlpatterns** like:

```py
 path('dashboard/<int:job_id>/update', views.update, name='dashboard'),
```

and then use this **view-name** in your `templates/views` for useful purposes. Like this

```py
return redirect('dashboard', job_id=job_id)
```

another way is to use `reverse` from **django.urls**.

```py
return redirect(reverse('dashboard', job_id=job_id)) # do the same job for you.
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `/` to your redirect function and it should work.

```
return redirect(f'/dashboard/{job_id}/update')
```

Its good practice if you give a name to your URL and use `reverse` function to get the URL in the code.

```
from news import views

path('dashboard/<int:job_id>/update', views.update, name='dashboard')
```

```
return redirect(reverse('dashboard', args=[job_id]))
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse